# fill array with recursive method

Tags: java, algorithm

I m trying to create a function  to fill array with the recursive method in java this is my code  (the parameter x is the size of the array):

```
public int[] genArr(int[] nums,int idx,int x){
    if(idx>x){
        return nums;
    }
   
    else{
    nums[idx] = idx;
    return genArr(nums,idx++,x--);
    }
     
}
```

but when run my function I have stackOverflow error.

Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems there:

1. The stack overflow issue you asked about.
2. The basic logic of the method.

The first problem is that `getArr(num, idx++, x--)` uses the *postfix* increment operator (the `++` is after the operand), so it passes the **current** value of `idx` to `getArr` and **then** increments the parameter's value. But nothing ever uses the incremented parameter value. So if `idx` is `0` and `x` is `10`, you're endlessly calling `getArr(nums, 0, 10)` until you overflow the stack. If you were going to use the increment operator, it would need to be the *prefix* increment operator where the `++` is in front of the operand (`++idx`), but there's no reason to use the increment operator: just use `idx + 1`.

The second problem is that even if you fix the above, by increasing `idx` and decreasing `x` and stopping when `idx > x` is true, you're going to miss out filling in most of the array. For instance, if you started with `idx` at `0` and `x` at `10`, your code would stop when `idx` was `6` and `x` was `4`, leaving the last several slots of your array uninitialized: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Instead, get rid of `x` entirely and make `idx >= nums.length` your termination condition:

```
public int[] genArr(int[] nums, int idx) {
// #2 No `x` −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    if (idx >= nums.length) {
// #2 −−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ compare with `nums.length`
        return nums;
    } else {
        nums[idx] = idx;
        return genArr(nums, idx + 1);
// #1 −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Technically, you could use `==` rather than `>=` because you only ever add `1` to `idx`, but I tend to be paranoid about array access guards like that and use `>=` instead (in case logic changes and we add more than `1` at some point).